# I am using Ipython and sympy to solve a system of equations

Tags: ipython, sympy, equations

I am trying to solve a system of equations and then have the results stored in variables variables for plotting or further calculation.

```
%pylab inline
from sympy import init_printing;init_printing()
from sympy import *
d,vf,a,vi,t,x,h,g,theta,ans=symbols('d vf a vi t x h g theta ans')
equations=[Eq(sin(theta),(0.5*g*t**2+h)/(vi*t)),Eq(cos(theta),x/(vi*t))]
ans=solve(equations,[h,t],dict=True)
```

but ans is just a single entry and I do not know how to get the equation for h by itself and the equation for t by itself. The results are however correct

thanks for any and all help ( I am using Ipython)

Comment: What version of sympy are you using? In 0.7.2 it works perfectly fine. `ans` is a list containing the single possible dictionary of solutions.

Comment: I get a list as well but the list only has a length of 1 so I can't separate out the two answers when I do len(ans) the result is 1 and if I ans[0] I get the entire answer

Comment: I am using canopy sympy ver 0.7.2

Comment: By the way, SymPy 0.7.3 is out now. You should use that instead. 0.7.2 is quite old in comparison.

Comment: thanks for your help and I will upgrade

Answer (score 0):

```
In [14]: ans
Out[14]:
⎡⎧              2                          ⎫⎤
⎢⎪       0.5⋅g⋅x                      x    ⎪⎥
⎢⎨h: - ─────────── + x⋅tan(θ), t: ─────────⎬⎥
⎢⎪       2    2                   vi⋅cos(θ)⎪⎥
⎣⎩     vi ⋅cos (θ)                         ⎭⎦
```

So you can see here, the answer is a list containing a dictionary. To get the first (and only) item of the list, use `ans[0]`. To get the elements of the dictionary, use `[key]` with the dictionary key, which in this case are the symbols you solved for. So to get the answers, you would do

```
In [16]: ans[0][h]
Out[16]:
           2
    0.5⋅g⋅x
- ─────────── + x⋅tan(θ)
    2    2
  vi ⋅cos (θ)

In [17]: ans[0][t]
Out[17]:
    x
─────────
vi⋅cos(θ)
```

Comment: thanks, if I retype the equation for h I can plot it, but if I use plotme=ans[0][h] and assign values for vi g and theta then I get an annoying error message that says the arrays are mismatched. I am using plot(plotme,(x,0,5))

Comment: That sounds like either a bug, or you are doing something wrong. Can you paste the output somewhere? I guess you can open a new question here for it.

Comment: I will enter it as a new question